# Sending HTML E-mails with JavaMail API for Android

Tags: android, html

I'm using the JavaMail API that's been ported for Android found [here](http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list) but I can't figure out how to send HTML formatted emails with it.

The activity to set up the email:

```
public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 
private String _user; 
private String _pass; 

private String[] _to; 
private String _from; 

private String _port; 
private String _sport; 

private String _host; 

private String _subject; 
private String _body; 

private boolean _auth; 

private boolean _debuggable; 

private Multipart _multipart; 


public Mail() { 
_host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server 
_port = "465"; // default smtp port 
_sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port 

_user = ""; // username 
_pass = ""; // password 
_from = ""; // email sent from 
_subject = ""; // email subject 
_body = " "; // email body 

_debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
_auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

_multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

// There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the      multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-  handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
} 

public Mail(String user, String pass) { 
this(); 

_user = user; 
_pass = pass; 
} 

public boolean send() throws Exception { 
Properties props = _setProperties(); 

if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) { 
  Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

  MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

  msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

  InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
  for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
    addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
  } 
    msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

  msg.setSubject(_subject); 
  msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

  // setup message body 
  BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
  messageBodyPart.setContent(_body, "text/html"); 
  _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

  // Put parts in message 
  msg.setContent(_multipart ); 

  // send email 
  Transport.send(msg); 

  return true; 
} else { 
  return false; 
} 
} 

public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

_multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
} 

@Override 
public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
} 

private Properties _setProperties() { 
Properties props = new Properties(); 

props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

if(_debuggable) { 
  props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
} 

if(_auth) { 
  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
} 

props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 

return props; 
} 

public void setTo(String[] _to) {
this._to = _to;

}

public void setFrom(String _from) {
this._from = _from;

}

public void setSubject(String _subject) {
this._subject = _subject;

}

public void setBody(Spanned string) {
this._body=string.toString();

}
}
```

The activity trying to send the email:

```
Mail m = new Mail("email address", "password"); 

String[] toArr = {Email1, Email2}; 
m.setTo(toArr);  
m.setSubject("This is just a test"); 

String sb=("Android</br>Testing</br><b> test </b>");


m.setBody(Html.fromHtml(sb)); 

try { 
  m.addAttachment("/sdcard/+"Image1.PNG"); 

  if(m.send()) { 
    Toast.makeText(this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
  } else { 
    Toast.makeText(this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
  } 
} catch(Exception e) { 
  //Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "There was a problem sending the email.",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
  Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
 } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GMAILSender class. Take a look at [this link](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/22/android-send-email-via-gmail-actually-via-smtp/)

Instead of using text/plain , try to use text/html in GmailSender.java

Answer (score 1):

in your code, instead of using "text/html" only use "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1". It should work. The string of the message must have the html tags already. For example...

```
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setContent("my message in html <br /> <strong> text in bold </strong>", "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");

multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this specific example, I did the same as rodrigoa points out below. If you followed [this tutorial](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android), then do the following. Once you get a successful html page you change it as you like.

```
sMail.setFrom("wooo@wooo.com"); 
sMail.setSubject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device."); 

/* Notice the html tags below. You could use StringBuilder to send a Google Map
 * of whatever other HTML content you want here. */
sMail.setBody("<HTML><CENTER><H1>IT WORKS</H1><C/ENTER></HTML>");
```

Then in your main activity, change it to the following:

```
// setup message body 
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
messageBodyPart.setContent(_body, "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"); 
_multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

Hope this saves someone some time.